# Getting "Invalid Azure Credentials" trying to enable Mongo Atlas encryption at rest

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to [configure Atlas with Customer Key Management](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-kms-encryption/#configure-service-with-customer-key-management)
 which seems fairly straightforward. However, if I create a new service principal/app registration in Azure to connect Mongo Atlas to my Azure key vault I get `Invalid Azure Credentials` as an error.

I create the service principal following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app#register-an-application) without any redirect URI. I tried all different account types but none worked for me. After creation, I create a new client secret and use it in the 'Secret'-field inside the Mongo Atlas UI.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to add the service principal as a Key Vault Reader to the subscription that holds the key vault.

Relevant documentation: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-azure-kms/#prerequisites

Comment: Hi leonheess, I fixed the same issue after add the service principal as a Key Vault Crypto Officer. Btw how did you find this solution? I don't see it methioned on mongodb documentation.

Comment: Hi leonheess, I checked mongo documentation, "key Vault Reader" role is required.
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-azure-kms/#prerequisites